# Proving $\Box(p \land q) \rightarrow (\Box p \land \Box q)$ in modal system $K$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic

I need to prove $\Box(p \land q) \rightarrow (\Box p \land \Box q)$.

Currently, I know of a proof that utilizes the tautology $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ as a first premise, from which we use the necessity axiom to induce $\Box((p \land q) \rightarrow p))$. We can then use the $K$ axiom and go from there.

However, my professor is adamant that if I am to use this tautology as a premise, I have to prove it's a tautology without truth tables, so I am looking to avoid using it.

My question is: Is there any other way of proving my original modal statement?

Comment: Do you know natural deduction? If so, you can always apply the Necessitation Rule and derive the “boxed” version of an implication proven from no premises. If you’re in an axiomatic system, this is just an axiom and its proof is a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are doing an axiomatic proof
\begin{align}
1.& p\land q\to p\tag*{PL}\\
2.& \square(p\land q\to p)\tag*{1, NEC}\\
3.& \square(p\land q)\to \square p\tag*{2, K}\\
4.& p\land q\to q\tag*{PL}\\
5.& \square(p\land q\to q)\tag*{4, NEC}\\
6.& \square(p\land q)\to \square q\tag*{5, K}\\
7.& \square(p\land q)\to(\square p\land\square q)\tag*{3,6 PL}
\end{align}